# Vue js изменить свойство объекта в цикле

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть кусок шаблона:

```html
<div class="element" v-for="(element, index) in formElements" :key="index">
  <div class="element-content">
    <div class="number">
      {{ element.priority = index + 1 }}.
    </div>
    <select v-model="element.selected" required>
      <option value="" disabled hidden selected>
        Choose a option
      </option>
      <option v-for="(label, optionIndex) in formData" :key="optionIndex" :value="label.name" :disabled="matchSelected(label.name)">
        {{ label.title }}
      </option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" class="button button--sort" @click="element.sort = changeSort(element.sort)">
      <img :src="element.sort === 'ASC' ? getImgUrl('sort-ASC.svg') : getImgUrl('sort-DESC.svg')" alt="">
    </button>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="button button--delete" @click="deleteLabel(index)">
    <img src="../assets/clear.svg" alt="">
  </button>
</div>
```

Мне нужно привязать`element.priority` и `index`, что я и делаю в интерполяции, но думаю, что это *bad practice*.

Как лучше в таком случае сделать реактивную привязку?

Comment: Свойство `priority` нужно контролировать при формировании и изменении массива объектов `formElements`. Либо сам массив нужно сортировать по данному полю `priority`. Тогда Vue будет сам перестраивать порядок элементов при отрисовке шаблона.

Comment: Любые вычисления, присваивания, сравнения в представлении - это [*bad practice*](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html). Отделяйте `view` от `model`.

Comment: Смапьте предварительно массив formElements с помощью Array.map() добавив туда priority. Вы же его откуда-то получаете, верно?

Answer (score 0):

```
computed: {
  computedFormElements() {
    return this.formElements.map( (_, index) => ({
      ..._,
      priority: index + 1,
    }))
  }
}
```

И уже в цикле использовать измененный массив, в нем **priority** будет в нужном виде.

```
<div class="element" v-for="(element, index) in computedFormElements" :key="index">
```